# Current sense transformer outside its freq range

Tags: current, transformer, frequency, sense

What happens if I use a current sense transformer outside its specified frequency range? For example a transformer is rated for 20-200 kHz but I want to use it to measure 50 Hz power line frequency stuff. What happens? I'm guessing the output current for measuring will be very low? What if I compensate by choosing a very large value burden resistor? I would need to monitor primary currents from 20 mA up to 750 mA or so.

The reason for not choosing a 50 Hz transformer in the first place is that there doesn't seem to be one available which is either surface mount or through hole mounted, and which doesn't require me to manually route a wire through its core.

Comment: It is 20 kilohertz. So orders of magnitude higher.

Comment: The CT for 20khz has too low inductance to measure 50hz. It will probably involve a phase shift between prim. and sec.  sides or even output sine will be distored.

Comment: There are two types of CTs.  Use a 50/60hz one, not the high frequency type.  Power line CTs have much higher inductance.   A CT has inductance and a load resistor.  At low frequencies the inductance shorts out the resistor.  Using the 20-200khz example and say the resistor is 100 ohms.  At 200khz the transformer's inductance is the same as 3000 ohms but at 20khz it is 300 ohms.  At 2khz it is 30 ohms and at 200 hz it is 3 ohms.  At power line frequency it is less than 1 ohm.  This 1 ohm shorts out the 100 ohm resistor used to measure current.

Comment: @ronsimpson we try not to answer questions in comments. Would you like to rewrite that comment as an asnwer?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this is very helpful and I now understand why choosing a high frequency CT is not a good idea.

Comment: Please link the data sheet of device you mentioned in your question